# SQL with nested condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**EDIT:** added third requirement after playing with solution from Tim Biegeleisen

**EDIT2:** modified Robbie's DOB to be before his parent's marriage date

I am trying to create a query that will look at two tables and determine the difference in dates based on a percentage. I know, super confusing... Let me try and explain using the tables below:

- Bob and Mary are married on `2010-01-01` and expect 4 kids (`Parent table`)
- I want to know how many years it took until they met 50% of their expected kids (i.e. 2/4 kids). Using the `Child table` to see the DOB of their 4 kids, we know that Frankie is the second child which meets our 50% threshold so we use Frankie's DOB and subtract it from Frankie's parent's marriage date and end up with 3 years!
- If the goal isn't reached then display no value e.g. Mick and Jo only had 1 child so far so they haven't yet reached their goal

Hoping this is doable using BigQuery standard SQL.

---

```
Parent table
id  married_couple  married_at  expected_kids
--------------------------------------
1   Bob and Mary    2010-01-01  4
2   Mick and Jo     2010-01-01  4     

Child table
id  child_name  parent_id  date_of_birth  
--------------------------------------
1   Eddie       1          2012-01-01     
2   Frankie     1          2013-01-01     
3   Robbie      1          2005-01-01     
4   Duncan      1          2015-01-01     
5   Rick        2          2014-01-01     

Expected SQL result
parent_id  half_goal_reached(years)
--------------------------------------
1          3
2
```

Comment: Do you want to round down or up?

Comment: I guess i can figure out the rounding using whatever functions there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below both soluthions for BigQuery Standard SQL
First one is more in classic sql way, the second one is more of BigQuery style (I think)

> First Solution: with analytics function

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  parent_id, 
  IF(
    MAX(pos) = MAX(CAST(expected_kids / 2 AS INT64)), 
    MAX(DATE_DIFF(date_of_birth, married_at, YEAR)), 
    NULL
  ) AS half_goal_reached
FROM (
  SELECT c.parent_id, c.date_of_birth, expected_kids, married_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.parent_id ORDER BY c.date_of_birth) AS pos
  FROM `child` AS c
  JOIN `parent` AS p 
  ON c.parent_id = p.id
)
WHERE pos <= CAST(expected_kids / 2 AS INT64)
GROUP BY parent_id
```

> Second Solution: with use of ARRAY

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  parent_id, 
  DATE_DIFF(dates[SAFE_ORDINAL(CAST(expected_kids / 2 AS INT64))], married_at, YEAR) AS half_goal_reached
FROM (
  SELECT 
    parent_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(date_of_birth ORDER BY date_of_birth) AS dates, 
    MAX(expected_kids) AS expected_kids,
    MAX(married_at) AS married_at
  FROM `child` AS c
  JOIN `parent` AS p 
  ON c.parent_id = p.id
  GROUP BY parent_id
)
```

> Dummy Data

You can test / play with both solutions using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `parent` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Bob and Mary' married_couple, DATE '2010-01-01' married_at, 4 expected_kids UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Mick and Jo', DATE '2010-01-01', 4     
),
`child` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Eddie' child_name, 1 parent_id, DATE '2012-01-01' date_of_birth UNION ALL     
  SELECT 2, 'Frankie', 1, DATE '2013-01-01' UNION ALL     
  SELECT 3, 'Robbie', 1, DATE '2014-01-01' UNION ALL     
  SELECT 4, 'Duncan', 1, DATE '2015-01-01' UNION ALL     
  SELECT 5, 'Rick', 2, DATE '2014-01-01' 
)
```

Comment: So i spent a lot of today making a lot of progress thanks to your solution above. The one thing that I realised with my live data is that it accommodates for DOBs that are before a marriage. For example, switch Robbie's DOB to be `2005-01-01` and watch the strange result being produced. I've tried a few things but haven't hd any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried second solution (with array) - I think it still produces correct result. please confirm

Comment: Yep, I've been using the second solution but I think the problem is that it doesn't order the dates within the array, so it spits out the wrong result. I'll try it again and post my results here.

Comment: oops, somehow missed ordering. i think i thought you will dig by yourself. anyway, see updated answer.

Comment: (facepalm) I was trying to run the order outside of the arr_agg function! Can't believe I missed this in the docs :( THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query, whose logic is too verbose to explain it well.  I join the parent and child tables, bringing into line the parent id, number of years elapsed since marriage, running number of children, and expected number of children.  With this information in hand, we can easily find the first row whose running number of children matches or exceeds half of the expected number.

```
SELECT parent_id, num_years AS half_goal_reached
FROM
(
    SELECT parent_id, num_years, cnt, expected_kids,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num_years) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t2.parent_id,
            YEAR(t2.date_of_birth) - YEAR(t1.married_at) AS num_years,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child c
             WHERE c.parent_id = t2.parent_id AND
                   c.date_of_birth <= t2.date_of_birth) AS cnt,
            t1.expected_kids
        FROM parent t1
        INNER JOIN child t2
            ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
    ) t
    WHERE
        cnt >= expected_kids / 2
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Note that there may be issues with how I computed the yearly differences, or how I compute the threshhold for half the number of expected children.  Also, if we were using a recent enterprise database we could have used an analytic function to get the running number of children instead of a correlated subquery, but I was unsure if Big Query would support that, so I used the latter.

Comment: Wow.... I am going to try this but I am still trying to get my head around all of your sub-queries.

Comment: Is an `analytic function` function similar to a User-defined Function in BigQuery? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

Comment: No...an example of an analytic function which BigQuery does support is °ROW_NUMBER` and I have used it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Reading up on it now

Comment: It worked! Except it brought to light that the WHERE clause excluded all parents that hadn't reached their target yet. I made an update to the original question for completeness of my problem but thank you so much for the main solution!